# How to use FormsAuthentication with logins stored in SQL Server DB table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, formsauthentication

I am making a new web application in ASP.NET (in C#) using FormsAuthentication for the login. A standard FormsAuthentication setup is in place currently, with usernames and passwords specified in the web.config as usual, and this setup is working great. However,

I would like to link this login setup to an SQL Server table in the database. This table stores user account information for each user, including username and password. Basically, I would like to find a way so that the following line of code will look for a username and password in this DB table, rather than in the web.config as it normally does:

FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txt_username.Text, txt_password.Text);

But I'm at a loss as to how to do this exactly.
I've been reading about Membership.ValidateUser, but I still cannot find how to use that to link to the usernames and passwords in the users table in the database.

Any help will be highly appreciated! 
(Btw, this is my first post, so please feel free to point out any noob mistakes I may have made).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom MembershipProvider.

The `MembershipProvider` is the mechanism that your application will use to authenticate users as well as handle user-related functionality (change password, unlock users, etc).  A custom MembershipProvider is nothing more than a class which extends the `MembershipProvider` abstract class.  This is where you'll write custom logic to interface with your database to perform the required membership actions (validate credentials, create user, change password, etc).

Have a look at this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) is a good resource if you are unfamiliar with ASP.NET Membership.

Comment: Thank you, I looked into both of those resources, but eventually figured out my problem: I thought the following line of code was the line responsible for authentication:  

FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txt_username.Text, txt_password.Text)  

However, now I realize this line simply validates whether a user exists, and if so, whether the password matches with it. Now I know it does not actually log the user into the site. The line that actually does the logging in is:  

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txt_username.Text, true);  

But thank you very much for your help! :)